# Can Flex popupManager share and center popups for a whole HTML page?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, popup

I have to put multiple Flash movies on a page and I'd like them to share modal popups, so that access to the entire page is denied while a popup is active. I can do this via Javascript and create HTML popups via the `ExternalInterface` class, but I would love to be able to do this entirely in Flex using the `PopupManager` class.

Note: This is not for any evil purpose. I just need to make sure none of the other movies' buttons are clicked before the user responds to the first thing they clicked. Also, some of the movies are quite small and can't contain some of the popups they require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Flex or Flash App is going to be limited to to "Box" the browser puts it in.  You can't use PopUpMAnager to position elements outside of that box while still maintaining their visibility.  They'd show up "off screen."

I don't think the PopUpManager can do what you want to do.

You may be able to set something up w/ LocalConnection to disable the other SWFs while a dialog box is open in one of them.